# Does easy_install provide search command?

Tags: python, easy-install, package-managers

Sometimes I need to guess the package name, is there any package search utilites such as the search command in apt/yum/port/brew...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can search online at [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), which is the database that easy_install, pip et al use.